# How to fix: adb does not recognize my android device (android 4.0)

Tags: android, adb, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

When i try `adb shell` it shows error device not found
My device that i mentioned is:
Huawei Ascend D1 quad XL
Model:U9510E
OS:Android 4.0
Kernel Version:3.0.8-02106-g92c8d16

I am on Windows.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Check the Windows device manager if the USB devices from the phone have the correct driver assigned.

Answer (score 0):

On that old of a device, it is probably a bad connection on the data cable connectors on the phone. Try making sure you are on a usb cable that is not charge-only...

Run `lsusb` to see if device is even seen when you plug it in, on a Linux/unix based machine?

Comment: i am on windows

Comment: but i am sure the connection is still good

Comment: You see it in devices or something? In that case maybe you need the phone vendor's specific driver.

Comment: i see it in devices it named "MTP"